# Java Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I add Maven support for an existing project. I found some libraries and I don't have any ideas of their usages :

```
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPIMonitor;
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPIMonitorException;
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPIRequestException;
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPITransfer;
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPITransferFilter;
import axway.xfb.jpi.JPITransferRequest;
```

axway.xjb.jpi - I do not find any maven dependecy for this one. For what does JPI stands for ?

If someone could help with some information about what this libraries were used for, in order to could update the code, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes look like they were imported from a package from an existing project. Check the project to see if there are any classes in your project matching those.
I don't think you can find those on Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Java Prolog Interface (JPI) is an Application Provider Interface (API) for interaction between Java and Prolog programming languages. Is a bidirectional interface that communicate Java applications with Prolog program or database and Prolog procedures with Java class and methods.

JPI is an abstraction layer over concrete prolog drivers over Prolog Engines. This API define all mechanism to interact with any Prolog Engine and maintain the application independent to a specific underlying engine. JPI have several connectors to open source prolog engines like SWI, YAP, XSB native engines and tuProlog, jTrolog, jLog Java based prolog engines.

JPI study all related Java-Prolog integration libraries and take the betters features from each solution with the propose to achieve a common integration interface. The last feature allows switch the under laying Prolog Engine driver and the application code still be the same.

JPI run over any Java Virtual Machine that support Java SE 5 or above. The project was tested over HotSpot and Open J9 Virtual Machines over Operating Systems like Windows (7,8,10), Linux (Debian, Ubuntu) and Mac OS X. Can be deployed on Servlets Containers like Jetty, Tomcat or Glassfish Application Server. JPI can be include in any Java Project using the commonest Java Integration Development Enviroment (IDE) like Eclipse, Netbeans, IntellijIDEA and so on.

JPI is developed and maintained by Prolobjectlink Project an open source initiative for build logic based applications using Prolog like fundamental Logic Programming Language in the persistence layer and application programming.

I hope these links can help:
https://docs.axway.com/bundle/TransferCFT_36_UsersGuide_allOS_en_HTML5/page/Content/Prog/API/java_api.htm

Source: https://github.com/prolobjectlink/prolobjectlink-jpi